# Why is Dapper parameter in SQL 'WHERE' clause case sensitive?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, dapper

---

### Problem Description

---

When using a Dapper parameter in an SQL `WHERE`-clause, the parameter appears to be case sensitive. However, when I replace the Dapper parameter with a string literal, the `WHERE`-clause is no longer case sensitive. I have created a simple ASP.NET Core [recipe example web API](https://github.com/zwoolli/recipeExample) to help illustrate the problem.

In this recipe example, I am using a `PostgreSQL` database and want to query a [recipe table](https://github.com/zwoolli/recipeExample/blob/main/sql/Recipe.sql) to get a recipe by name. I have made the `name` column of type [`citext`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/citext.html), which is a case-insensitive string type.

---

### Database Table

---

A description of the `recipe` table:

```
+-------------+--------+-----------+----------+--------------------+
|   Column    |  Type  | Collation | Nullable |      Default       |
+-------------+--------+-----------+----------+--------------------+
| recipe_id   | uuid   |           | not null | uuid_generate_v4() |
| name        | citext |           | not null |                    |
| description | text   |           |          |                    |
+-------------+--------+-----------+----------+--------------------+
```

The contents of the `recipe` table are:

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|              recipe_id               |        name        |                        description                        |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 8f749e7a-e192-48df-91af-f319ab608212 | meatballs          | balled up meat                                            |
| f44c696f-a94a-4f17-a387-dd4d42f60ef8 | red beans and rice | yummy new orleans original                                |
| 82c5911b-feec-4854-9073-6a85ea793dc0 | pasta cereal       | couscous and ground meat eaten with a spoon, like cereal! |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

### Query Method

---

The `RecipeController` has a [`GetByName`](https://github.com/zwoolli/recipeExample/blob/main/src/Controllers/RecipeController.cs#L26) method that accepts the `name` parameter as part of the URI path. The `GetByName` method calls the [`GetByNameAsync`](https://github.com/zwoolli/recipeExample/blob/6c103875737ee218ff75ec78124a8a421ff0bcdd/src/DataAccess/RecipeRepository.cs#L23) method of the `RecipeRepository` class, which contains the SQL statement in question:

```
public async Task<Recipe> GetByNameAsync(string name)
{
    string sql = $@"
                    SELECT  *
                    FROM    {nameof(Recipe)}
                    WHERE   {nameof(Recipe)}.{nameof(Recipe.name)} = @{nameof(name)}";
    
    using (IDbConnection connection = Open())
    {
        IEnumerable<Recipe> recipes = await connection.QueryAsync<Recipe>(sql, new {name});

        return recipes.DefaultIfEmpty(new Recipe()).First();
    }
}
```

---

### Query Responses

---

If I wanted to query the **meatballs** recipe by name, and set the `name` parameter equal to "meatballs", I get the following response:

```
{
  "recipe_id": "8f749e7a-e192-48df-91af-f319ab608212",
  "name": "meatballs",
  "description": "balled up meat"
}
```

Setting the `name` parameter equal to "Meatballs", I get the following response:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4",
  "title": "Not Found",
  "status": 404,
  "traceId": "00-5e4e35d5cfec644fc117eaa96e854854-c0490c8ef510f3b1-00"
}
```

And finally, if I replace the Dapper `name` parameter with the string literal "Meatballs":

```
public async Task<Recipe> GetByNameAsync(string name)
{
    string sql = $@"
                    SELECT  *
                    FROM    {nameof(Recipe)}
                    WHERE   {nameof(Recipe)}.{nameof(Recipe.name)} = 'Meatballs'";
    
    using (IDbConnection connection = Open())
    {
        IEnumerable<Recipe> recipes = await connection.QueryAsync<Recipe>(sql, new {name});

        return recipes.DefaultIfEmpty(new Recipe()).First();
    }
}
```

I get the following response:

```
{
  "recipe_id": "8f749e7a-e192-48df-91af-f319ab608212",
  "name": "meatballs",
  "description": "balled up meat"
}
```

**Why is this Dapper parameter forcing case-sensitivity? And how can I get around this?**

Comment: Presumably Dapper isn't doing any such thing and the same thing happens from any language where a parameter is passed as a regular string -- the parameter type has to be inferred, after all, and the `citext` type is never going to be inferred, if there was a way of specifying that as a type name at all. Try `@{nameof(name)}::citext` instead, to cast the parameter value after passing it. Of course if comparing `citext` and other string types works this way it does somewhat diminish the usefulness. (I should add I have no actual experience with `citext`.)

Comment: From what I gather Postgres also supports collations, and using a case-insensitive collation on a regular string type is likely to work without conversion of any kind. The [PG docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#COLLATION-NONDETERMINISTIC) do note that these come with performance penalties since they must be declared as non-deterministic. You also set yourself up for possible collation conflicts, of course, so it's not necessarily a better solution.

Comment: I would crank up the Postgres logging temporarily to include `all` statements and see what is actually hitting the database. It might give you a clue as to what `Dapper` is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: @PoulBak, that does not explain why `"name": "meatballs"`  works but `"name": "MeatBalls"` does not ?

Comment: @PoulBak: no, `@{nameof(name)}` in an interpolated string yields `@name`, which, in a query string, is interpreted as a parameter name, the value of which is supplied in the call (through the anonymous object with a `name` property). Read the question again; searching for `meatballs` with the *first* version returns results. Had the OP written `'@{nameof(name)}'` you'd have a point.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - I have used [`pg_stat_statements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstatstatements.html#id-1.11.7.39.10) to view the queries hitting the database. Parameters are substituted with arguments (ex: "$1"). So the query that I can see is `SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE recipe.name = $1`

Comment: @JeroenMostert - Casting the `@name` parameter to `citext` using `@{nameof(name)}::citext` worked! The query hitting the database is `SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE recipe.name = $1::citext`. I'll have a look into collations. I am unfamiliar with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

### Background

---

As [Jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) pointed out:

> *Presumably Dapper isn't doing any such thing and the same thing happens from any language where a parameter is passed as a regular string...*

This indeed was not an issue with Dapper, but an issue with SQL data types. The `name` column in the `recipeExample` database does not know the incoming data type is supposed to be of type `citext`. Therefore, casting the incoming argument to `citext` is necessary.

As [Jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) also pointed out:

> *From what I gather Postgres also supports collations, and using a case-insensitive collation on a regular string type is likely to work without conversion of any kind.*

Somehow I missed this, but the [pgDocs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/citext.html) even recommend considering [*nondeterministic collations*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#COLLATION-NONDETERMINISTIC) instead of using the `citext` module. After reading up on [localization](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/locale.html), [collations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html), and watching [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0lP_K1rd98), I updated the [recipe example web api](https://github.com/zwoolli/recipeExample) to compare using the `citext` module with nondeterministic collations.

---

### Database Update

---

First, I added the [`case_insensitive`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#COLLATION-NONDETERMINISTIC) collation provided in the PostgreSQL documentation:

```
CREATE COLLATION case_insensitive (provider = icu, locale = 'und-u-ks-level2', deterministic = false);
```

Then, I updated the [`recipe`](https://github.com/zwoolli/recipeExample/blob/main/sql/Recipe.sql) table to have two name columns: `name_1` of type `text` using the `case_insensitive` collation, and `name_2` of type `citext`:

```
+-------------+--------+------------------+----------+--------------------+
|   Column    |  Type  |    Collation     | Nullable |      Default       |
+-------------+--------+------------------+----------+--------------------+
| recipe_id   | uuid   |                  | not null | uuid_generate_v4() |
| name_1      | text   | case_insensitive | not null |                    |
| name_2      | citext |                  | not null |                    |
| description | text   |                  |          |                    |
+-------------+--------+------------------+----------+--------------------+
Indexes:
    "recipe_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (recipe_id)
    "recipe_name_citext_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (name_2)
    "recipe_name_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (name_1)
```

Next, I created three Postgres functions to test out the 'Meatballs' query:

1. The first function queries the `name_1` column and takes a `text` argument
2. The second function queries the `name_2` column and takes a `text` argument
3. The third function queries the `name_2` column and takes a `citext` argument

```
CREATE FUNCTION getrecipe_name1_text(text) RETURNS recipe as $$
    SELECT *
    FROM recipe
    WHERE recipe.name_1 = $1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE FUNCTION getrecipe_name2_text(text) RETURNS recipe as $$
    SELECT *
    FROM recipe
    WHERE recipe.name_2 = $1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE FUNCTION getrecipe_name2_citext(citext) RETURNS recipe as $$
    SELECT *
    FROM recipe
    WHERE recipe.name_2 = $1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

---

### Query Tests

---

Querying the `name_1` column with `text` argument:

```
recipeexample=# SELECT * FROM getrecipe_name1_text('Meatballs');

+--------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
|              recipe_id               |  name_1   |  name_2   |  description   |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
| 8f749e7a-e192-48df-91af-f319ab608212 | meatballs | meatballs | balled up meat |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
(1 row)
```

Querying the `name_2` column with `text` argument:

```
recipeexample=# SELECT * FROM getrecipe_name2_text('Meatballs');

+-----------+--------+--------+-------------+
| recipe_id | name_1 | name_2 | description |
+-----------+--------+--------+-------------+
|           |        |        |             |
+-----------+--------+--------+-------------+
(1 row)
```

Querying the `name_2` column with `citext` argument:

```
recipeexample=# SELECT * FROM getrecipe_name2_citext('Meatballs');

+--------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
|              recipe_id               |  name_1   |  name_2   |  description   |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
| 8f749e7a-e192-48df-91af-f319ab608212 | meatballs | meatballs | balled up meat |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
(1 row)
```

---

### Conclusion

---

1. If the `citext` module is used, arguments must be cast to `citext` when querying
2. If the `case_insensitive` collation is used, there will be performance penalties and pattern matching operations are not possible